C++20: Standard-compliant way of getting the size of the allocation std::allocate_shared performs
I'm trying to use a boost::pool_allocator to (efficiently) allocate std::shared_ptr<T>. Conceptually, I want something like this:
struct Foo {};

std::shared_ptr<Foo> create() {
  static boost::pool_alloator<Foo> alloc;

  return std::allocate_shared<Foo>(alloc);
}

There is one problem with this example: boost::pool_allocator<Foo> is optimized for allocations of size sizeof(Foo) (in fact I'm surprised that it supports allocations of different sizes at all…). But std::allocate_shared<Foo>(…) does not allocate sizeof(Foo) bytes, because it allocates the control block and the payload in one go.
To efficiently use boost::pool_allocator<…> with std::allocate_shared, I would need to inform the pool_allocator about the size of the allocations to expect. To do that, I would probably need the type that allocate_shared allocates internally. I'm pretty sure that for GCC's STL implementation, that type would be _Sp_counted_ptr_inplace, and for Clang's libc++ it looks like it's __shared_ptr_emplace::_Storage - but using these types would obviously not be portable.
Is there any standard-compliant way of figuring out the size of the allocations that std::allocate_shared will perform? Or any other way to (efficiently) use a pool allocator for allocate_shared?

I wouldn't be surprised if there's no way to get this information, note that std::allocate_shared doesn't actually have to stick to using a single allocation https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/allocate_shared

Maybe related Custom (pool) allocator with boost shared_ptr

std lib is supposed to use allocator_traits::rebind_alloc and allocator_traits::rebind_traits internally(The asif rule applies). So the allocator is supposed to have a well-behaving rebind template type member.

The allocator is rebound to the internal type of whatever it is allocating, and a copy of the allocator with the appropriate type is used instead.
pool_allocator<Foo> is a bit misleading since it is rebound to the larger type. Usually, you use allocator<void> when you know it will be rebound:
std::shared_ptr<Foo> create() {
  static boost::pool_allocator<void> alloc;

  return std::allocate_shared<Foo>(alloc);
}

This way you know for sure no extra work is done to handle allocators for a smaller sized object that's never actually used

Ah, that's good to know, I did not know about this rebinding logic. If I understand you correctly, rebinding creates a new pool_allocator object. What is the lifetime of that object in this example? is that rebound allocator created (and destroyed) for every create() call? That would mean that the "pool" is basically useless…

@LukasBarth Yes I think so: A copy of the allocator is made to allocate the shared_ptr + control block, and another copy is stored in the control block to later delete. "Stateful" allocators are usually just a pointer to something else (e.g. local_pool p; pool_allocator<T>(&p)), so the copies are cheap. In pool_allocator's case, I think it's a pointer to a singleton

Yes, I just read the documentation of boost::pool_allocator again - indeed, there's a singleton pool behind the scenes, so everything should be fine (but I can also get rid of the static variable). Thanks a lot!
